# TiKZ decoration doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am trying to get TikZ decorations to work, but so far without success. In this minimal example, I am trying to compile an example found in pgfmanual.pdf in section 20.2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw decorate [decoration=zigzag] {(0,0) -- (2,2)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I always get this error

```
"! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/crosses'
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The section 20.2 is called *Specifying a Uniform Opacity* in the current version of PGF (2.10) and has nothing to do with decorations but transparency. I assume you have an older version. Some LaTeX distributions (e.g. Ubuntu TeXLive) don't update the packages often. It would be much better to state the section title instead.

Comment: Found it. In v2.10 it is section 21.2, named *Decorating a Subpath Using the Decorate Path Command*.

Comment: @Jake: There was no reason to delete your answer. I wrote my one in my editor to test it and didn't reload the page before posting mine, so I didn't saw yours. It's OK to have similar answers around. Just let the people decide which one to up-vote. I hope I didn't bullied you or something ;-)

Comment: General advice on the TikZ/PGF manual section numbering problem, include the name of the subsection and the version of TikZ/PGF that you're using.

Comment: I think the wrong error message was quoted. Shouldn't it be `/pgf/decoration/zigzag`?.`Anyway: /pgf/decoration/crosses` belongs to `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}` just in case someone else comes from google.

Comment: Yes, you might be right, although I can't reproduce that anymore.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to also load the (sub-)library for the particular decoration (`decorations.pathmorphing` for `zigzag`). See also section 51 *Decoration Library* for more information (using PGF 3.1.5b, the section number can be different for other versions).

One issue with the otherwise great `pgfmanual` is, that it is hard to know which libraries are required for the examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw decorate [decoration={zigzag}] {(0,0) -- (2,2)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree with you upon required libraries being not very well documented.

I will keep the changing section numbers in mind.